# Finding the center of gravity of a matrix

Tags: java

I'm supposed to read a file containing the values of the matrix, then the program has to return the centers of gravity of the same matrix, in the case of being more than one he will one return the first center of gravity.

This is what i was able to do so far, but the issue is that the program only return a 0 and after extensively looking on the internet and finding nothing i came here seeking help ,cause i honestly don't know what to do to solve this, any help will be very appreciated.

```
public class Matrix {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("matriz.txt")));

    int cont = 0;
    int size = 5;

    double[][] mat = new double[size][size];

    // read the file containing the matrix
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        for (int col = 0; col < mat.length; col++) {
            String[] line = sc.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
            for (int lin = 0; lin < line.length; lin++) {
                mat[col][lin] = Double.parseDouble(line[lin]);
            }
        }
    }
    // variables to store the center(s) of gravity
    int cent1 = 0;
    int cent2 = 0;

    // here the program runs through the matrix to find it's center
    for (int l = 0; l < size; l++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < size - 1; c++) {
            if (mat[c][l] == 0 && mat[c + 1][l] == 0) {
                cent1++;
            } else if (mat[c][l] == 1 && mat[c + 1][l] == 0) {
                cent2++;
        }
    }
}         

    System.out.println(">> Matrix");
    for (int lin = 0; lin < size; ++lin) {
        for (int col = 0; col < size; ++col)
            System.out.print(mat[col][lin] + " ");

        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(">> Central points of the matrix");
    System.out.println("Case 1: " + cent1);
    System.out.println("Case 2: " + cent2);
}
```

}

And this is the file that the program is reading, forgot to include before:

```
0.1 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.1
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.1 0.1
0.2 0.3 0.1 0.1 0.3
0.4 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.2
0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.1
```

Comment: Hey! Code in english please. And explain your approach for calculating the center, I cannot figure out by looking at the code. You need to provide details about the file as well if you want to help people reproduce your problem.

Comment: What is the center of gravity?
Also, you need to know that your file contains 5 lines, but you read 10 lines only on the first iteration.

Comment: @akuzminykh I made the corrections into the code, thanks for the tip. And my approach to calculate the center is this: i use both for loops in order to run through the matrix rows and columns to find the center point or points, then the if and else if to check if it found what i want in the 2d matrix, after that the program stores the position on the 'cent1' and cent2 variables for the rows and columns respectively, and then print it just before the program ends, at least that's what the program was supposed to do, but he only return a value of 0.

Comment: @ Mohammed Deifallah The 'center of gravity' is just another way to refer to the center of a matrix (at least according to my teacher). I just realized that i put the wrong file here so thanks for pointing it out, but even then 5 or 10 lines the program returns the same output, I've tested and it didn't make any difference...

Comment: Is the result supposed to be the cell where the center of gravity is?

Comment: @akuzminykh almost, the result is supposed to be the row and column of the center of the matrix, for example: Case 1: (3, 3), which is the exact output of the program according with the file that it's reading.

Comment: As asked previously, please describe precisely what you mean by “center of gravity” ?  You say “find the center point or points” - at present your code “finds” those by comparisons like `mat[c][l] == 0`, but since your sample array doesn’t have any 0 or 1 values your intent remains unclear.

Comment: So the “center of the matrix” (3,3) .... so the values in the matrix are not important ??

Comment: @racraman center of gravity == the middle position of the matrix that the program reads on the file, one of the requirements for this program was that the matrix was filled with values that variate between 0 and 1 ( 0,1 ; 0,5 ; 0,2 and so on), and yes the values in matrix are not that important, they just serve to be read by the program in order to find the exact center of the matrix.

Comment: @AlicePacheco Are you actually reflecting your own comments? It's literaly ambiguous.

Comment: Great :).  In that case, you don’t need to loop through the array at all, but can simply calculate `(size / 2)+0.5`.  However, that doesn’t strike me as much of an assignment (let alone why they would go to the trouble of specifying those values if they’re not important) , so I’m worried that you’ve misunderstood something in the problem.

Comment: @racraman Even confused with the exercise I managed to do a lot, but some without need and ended up exaggerating the complexity of the program on my head, but nevermind that your answer helped me get the program running the way as intended, thank you very much for the patience and i hope you have a awesome day :D

Comment: Thank you, and glad it helped .  One thing to remember in this game is that before you start writing a program, you must always have a clear concise picture of the end result, of what you want the program to achieve.  I don’t know if you’ve covered unit testing yet (eg Junit) , but if you have then the current practice is to write the tests BEFORE the main code, which therefore forces you to have that clear picture first (eg https://www.guru99.com/test-driven-development.html ).   Still, wishing you every success, and have fun with it :)